# "Copy" an artifact in Ivy

Tags: ant, publish, ivy

In Ivy I have a published artifact that is flagged with an **integration** status.  Our CI server continuously publishes the artifact when it detects changes in the source code.

At some point we reach a stable release point, and want to publish the artifact with a **release** status and an actual version number.  However, I'd rather not have to do any additional build processing (such as checking out the code and running a build script).  It would be much safer to simply take the artifact as presently published (as integration), and "copy" it to the new status and version.  My question is: can Ivy do this?

I'd rather not do this directly on the filesystem if possible, for a few reasons.  One way to do this is do a retrieve and then republish.  I am wondering if there were some cleaner way to do it on the repository itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using ivy. Promoting builds is normally a feature supported by repository managers, rather than build clients.

Nexus Pro has a [staging suite](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging.html) and Artifactory supports similar features.